# Implement toggle in dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have few dropdown lists and the common element in all is the `role="list"`. I would like to implement toggle when I click on one dropdown, it closes the other open dropdown.

```
<div id="dropdownList1" class="jqx-listbox jqx-reset jqx-rc-all jqx-widget" aria-multiselectable="false" role="list"></div>

<div id="dropdownList2" class="jqx-listbox jqx-reset jqx-rc-all jqx-widget" aria-multiselectable="false" role="list"></div>

<div id="dropdownList3" class="jqx-listbox jqx-reset jqx-rc-all jqx-widget" aria-multiselectable="false" role="list" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out : add ***onclick="closeOthers(this)"*** to all dropdown items and here is the function :

```
function closeOthers(selected_dd){    $.each($('.jqx-listbox[role="List"]'),function(i,v){
     $(v).removeClass('open');//close all
    });
$(selected_dd).addClass('open'); //here is how to select the item u want, then u can open it as u want
}
```

consider that i made ***open*** class by myself... you can use any ather logic!

Comment: Not working this solution.